# Vim with pathogen and solarized color scheme

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

[image: My vim screen with pathogen and solarized color scheme]

This is my screen of vim editor with pathogen and solarized color scheme.You can notice a dark line in the center.

What is the purpose of this line? When I try to do a split window using sp it splits the windown horizontally.

I don't want this line to appear on my screen? Is there a purpose to it?It would be great if someone could tell me what is causing this?

Comment: That option is empty by default. If you don't want it, why do you enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have colorcolumn set up in your `.vimrc`. Do you see anything similar to the following lines in your `.vimrc`. If yes, you can comment them out and verify if you still that line.

```
set colorcolumn=
hi ColorColumn guibg=#2d2d2d ctermbg=246
```